# Retrieve ( index, column ) pair based on value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a data frame in this format

```
       A    B     C      D

1      a    a     c      c 
2      c    b     a      a 
3      b    a     c      a
.
.
.
```

I'm looking to get all ( index , column ) pairs based on certain value of a row using data frame operations. All ( index, column, row value ) pairs will be unique.

I looked in to this question: [pythonic way to get index,column for value == 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520952/pythonic-way-to-get-index-column-for-value-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Although it's the exact same question as mine, the accepted answer to that question is kind of vague and I couldn't get what I was looking for based on those answers.

I also looked in to similar ones:

a) [Select specific index, column pairs from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819994/select-specific-index-column-pairs-from-pandas-dataframe)

b) [Python Pandas: Get index of rows which column matches certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value)

I tried this:

```
req_cols = df.columns [ ( new_df == "a" ).any() ]

req_inds = (df == "a").index
```

I was able to get index values, and column values separately but confused on how to combine them properly.

If I choose row value "a" I expected to get `[(1,A), (1,B) , (2,C), (2,D), (3,B), (3,D)]`

Any help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `where` and `stack`:

```
df.where(df.eq('a')).stack().index.values
```

Output:

```
array([(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (2, 'D'), (3, 'B'), (3, 'D')],
  dtype=object)
```